# How do I make one class to behave exactly as another class

Tags: oop, code-reuse

I have a class named Bike where I have written function performed by the bike. Now I have a different Bike2 class which I want to perform the exactly same functions as the Bike class.(I cannot use the Bike class inplace of Bike2 class) What construct do I use. I mean like duplicating classes rather than copy paste code.Is there an another way I can do it.

Comment: Look into inheritance.

Comment: why can't you use the same class ? Use inheritance is Bike2 has some more functionality in addition to Bike

Comment: [`extends`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options to avoid code duplication:

1. Object inheritance

   You have one parent class with common functionality and several subclasses
2. Object composition

   You have several classes that use another class providing the common functionality